# Intuition behind why the derivative of $\ln(cx)$ always equals $1/x$, for any $c>0$?

Tags: calculus

I understand how to prove that algebraically using implicit differentiation:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvANe.png)

However, when I hope to gain an understanding through the graphs, I had a hard time wrapping my head around why the transformed lnx function still has the same slope at every point of x as the parent function.

[Graphs of the 3 functions that I talked about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ob5v.png)

Comment: If you could grab the red graph of $\ln x$ and move it upwards by a distance $\ln 10$, you would find that it coincided exactly with the blue graph of $\ln 10x$. So the two graphs have the same slope at the same $x$-coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the identity $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$, which holds for all $a,b>0$.

Comment: Then the derivative of $\ln c$ is $0$ because it is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general way of asking the question. Let $c\neq0$.

In order for $f(x)$ and $g(x):=f(cx)$ to have the same slope for all $x$, we need $f'(x)\equiv g'(x)\equiv c\cdot f'(cx)$. (The $\equiv$ sign means that these equations need to hold for all values of $x$: in order words, these *functions* must be equal, not just coincide at a particular point $x$.)

Which functions $h$ have the property that $h(x)\equiv c\cdot h(cx)$? Or, in other words, $h(cx)\equiv c^{-1}\cdot h(x)$?

Geometrically, this last identity says that compressing the graph of $h$ horizontally by a factor of $c$ is the same as stretching the graph of $h$ vertically by a factor of $c^{-1}$.

Algebraically, you can see that any function of the form $ax^{-1}$ solves this functional equation. In fact, any sum of such functions will work, too: we can have $h(x)=\sum a_ix^{-1}$.

Note that you can see clearly that no polynomial will work, though: substituting $cx$ for $x$ in $\sum a_ix^i$ for $i\geq0$ will not allow you to factor $c^{-1}$ out of each term.